# Remover dependências do EF sem o uso da classe MyConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação removendo todas as dependências do EF e deixando apenas nas camadas necessárias: **Repositório** e **Aplicação**. Fiz um pequeno projeto para testar o funcionamento antes de aplicar no projeto real para evitar complicações, porém, a única forma que consegui rodar este projeto foi com o uso da classe **MyConfiguration**

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(
            System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
            System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

É possível remover as dependências do EF sem o uso dessa classe e sem retornar a exceção?

> **An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET
>   provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the
>   provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the
>   application config file.**

Segue o código exemplo:

**Classe Contexto**

```
using MvcNorthwindExemplo.Dominio;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcNorthwindExemplo.Repositorio
{
    public class DBNorthwindContext : DbContext
    {
        public DBNorthwindContext()
            : base(@"Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=NorthwindExemplo; Integrated Security=true")
        {            
        }

        public DbSet<Regiao> Regioes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Código do app.config da camada Repositório**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**package da camada Repositório**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.6" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Ado" version="1.7.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.9.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.EF6" version="1.6.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Mvc5" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

**Classe Aplicação**

```
using MvcNorthwindExemplo.Dominio;
using MvcNorthwindExemplo.Repositorio;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace MvcNorthwindExemplo.Aplicacao
{
    public class RegiaoAplicacao
    {
        public DBNorthwindContext db { get; set; }

    public RegiaoAplicacao()
    {
        db = new DBNorthwindContext();
    }

    public void AddRegiao(Regiao regiao)
    {
        db.Regioes.Add(regiao);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void UpdateRegiao(Regiao regiao)
    {
        db.Entry(regiao).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Excluir(long? id)
    {
        var regiao = db.Regioes.Where(r => r.RegiaoID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (regiao != null)
        {
            db.Regioes.Remove(regiao);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public Regiao GetRegiaoFind(long id)
    {
        return GetRegiaoAll().Where(r => r.RegiaoID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Regiao> GetRegiaoAll()
    {
        return db.Regioes.ToList();
    }        
}
}
```

**Código do app.config da camada Aplicação**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --> </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**package da camada Aplicação**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.6" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Ado" version="1.7.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.9.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.EF6" version="1.6.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Mvc5" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende.

O Entity Framework pede pelo menos um provedor de acesso a dados. Como neste caso você está usando SQL Server LocalDb para acesso ao banco, o Entity Framework precisa dessa dependência com `System.Data.SqlClient`. Se for outro banco de dados, naturalmente que o provedor vai ser outro. Veja exemplos de configurações para outros bancos de dados:

## SQL Server

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## SQL Server LocalDb

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## MySQL

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## Oracle

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## Firebird

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

## PostgreSQL

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
  </providers>
<entityFramework>
```

Agora, pra fazer o Entity Framework ser completamente agnóstico na inicialização, você teria que incrementar sua classe de configuração para receber os parâmetros do provedor dinamicamente.

Uma sugestão seria:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration(String providerInvariantName, DbProviderServices dbProviderService)
    {
        SetProviderServices(providerInvariantName, dbProviderService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer dizer fazendo uma implementação diferente da classe MyConfiguration, mas continuando usando ela? Você teria alguma sugestão de implementação que poderia postar?

Comment: @KellySoares Editei a resposta.

Comment: Cigano, o segundo parâmetro do construtor é IDbDependencyResolver dbProviderService mesmo?

Comment: Sim, é. A interface é mais genérica.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo usar ele, me retorna dois erros: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration.SetProviderServices(string, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices)' has some invalid arguments e o erro Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.IDbDependencyResolver' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'

Comment: Ok, acho que vamos ter que usar o objeto mesmo. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Com object não é. Isso é certeza.

Comment: O problema está sendo no segundo parâmetro do tipo DbProviderServices

Comment: Não entendi seu problema agora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29417/discussion-between-kelly-soares-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Comment: Fechei o visual studio depois de fazer o clean e funcionou. Obrigada Cigano!